# Submit via javascript doesn't send the textbox value

Tags: javascript, post, submit

Interesting problem.  I have a client who wants the add to cart button to be an image.  That's fine, submit via javascript in an onclick on the image.  But when I look at the values being sent, quantity is always 1 (or whatever I set it as in the code).  In other words, I can't change the value of quantity.

```
<form name="AddToCartForm<?=$index?>" id="AddToCartForm<?=$index?>" action="[cartaddress]" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="insert" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$subcategory['Name'];?>" name="category" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$item['ProductNumber'];?>" name="prodnumber" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$item['Name'];?>" name="prodname" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$item['Price'];?>" name="prodprice" />
    <input type="hidden" value=".10" name="handling"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="10" name="weight" />
    <p><?=$item['Description'];?></p>
    <p><strong>Quantity:</strong>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="quantity" size="10" value="1"/></p>
    <p><strong>Price:</strong>&nbsp;$<?=number_format($item['Price'], 2);?></p>
    <p>
        <img onclick="document.getElementById('AddToCartForm'+<?=$index?>).submit();" style="cursor:pointer;" src="images/cart_button.png" width="100" height="111" alt="add to cart" />
    </p>
</form>
```

(If I use a submit button, the quantity goes through.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<input type="image">` instead of `<img>`. It acts like submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onlcick` merely submits, it doesn't do anything to change the value of `quantity`...so it's doing what you told it to. Before submitting you need to read the value of `quantity`, add 1 to that, and write the new value back to `quantity`.

Comment: I think the user is perfectly capable of changing the value of the input itself - it's a text box.

Comment: @Daan Wilmer - Ok, snarky, the OP left some things open to assumption. He didn't say anything about manually changing the value, though I see it is possibly implied. *My* bad.

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution is already given, I think I got the cause of the problem:

```
 document.getElementById('AddToCartForm'+<?=$index?>).submit();
```

I think the 'onclick' submits the wrong form. Would it also work if you changed it to `document.getElementById('AddToCartForm<?=$index?>').submit();`?